# How to make sweetalert2 not hide scrollbars on non-scrollable pages?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sweetalert2

Now I have a problem with sweetalert2.
I have a website at some pages need to be scrolled Some pages do not need to be scrolled.
So I solved it by using

```
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**My problem** now is
if sweetalert2 works in web page that cannot be scrolled up and down (but keep scrollbars on with `overflow-y: scroll;`)
This will cause the scroll bar to disappear and the site's position to move.

which if I use `backdrop: false`
It would solve my problem, but my background would disappear.
and it won't be pretty

But if it's a web page that can scroll up and down will not have this problem
What should I do to fix it :(

sweetalert2 doesn't hide scrollbars when used
`overflow-y: scroll` on pages that cannot be scrolled
to make the page not move

```
html.swal2-shown,
body.swal2-shwon {
  overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

not work